# How do I get the highest value in a database column?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a database, with a bunch of different columns. Let's say it looks like this:

```
   TABLE: dbtable
 __________________________________
|  onecolumn  |  id   |  twocolumn |
|---------------------|------------|
|   some      |   1   |  matchthis |
|  random     |   2   |  dontmatch |
|  thing      |   3   |  matchthis |
|   here      |   4   |  dontmatch |
|__________________________________|
```

I also have a Node.js program (using Sequelize), that is supposed to sort through the `dbtable` table, and find the row that has the highest ID value, as well as has twocolumn equal "matchthis". (all of these values are examples).
The code looks something like this:

```
const rel = await dbtable.findOne({
        where: {
            twocolumn: req.params.twocolumn // Url param that equals "matchthis"
        },
        order: Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('id')),
    });
```

However, instead of returning `{"onecolumn": "thing", "id": "3", "twocolumn": "matchthis"}`, it returns this error:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: Expression #1 of ORDER BY contains aggregate function and applies to the result of a non-aggregated query
```

I'm not very good with Databases, and i can't seem to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't contain a `GROUP BY` clause making it a 'non-aggregated query' as the error suggests, making it incompatible with ordering by an aggregating function (`MAX()`).

You can order directly on the `id` column instead.

```
const rel = await dbtable.findOne({
    where: {
        twocolumn: req.params.twocolumn
    },
    order: [
        [ 'id', 'DESC' ]
    ]
});
```